# How to halt compilation and output error message to the console with expl3?

Tags: errors, expl3, latex3, terminal-output

How to stop compliation and output an error message if conditional statement resolves to true?

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \bool_set_true:N\l_tmpa_bool % OUTPUT ERROR
  \bool_if:NTF\l_tmpa_bool
    { % OUTPUT ERROR TO CONSOLE
    }
    { NO ERROR
    }
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\msg_new:nnn(n)` to declare an error message, then use `\msg_fatal:nn(nnnn)` to raise a fatal error message, after which the compilation is aborted (see the [`l3msg` module documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#page=154) for more options):

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Declare message
\msg_new:nnnn { bp2017 } { logical-error }
  { The~thing~that~wasn't~supposed~to~happen~happened. }
  { I~don't~know~how~to~help~you~further. }%
%
\bool_set_true:N \l_tmpa_bool % OUTPUT ERROR
\bool_if:NTF \l_tmpa_bool
  { \msg_fatal:nn { bp2017 } { logical-error } }
  { NO ERROR }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\typeout{I'm still here!}
\end{document}
```

After that the terminal shows (note that `I'm still here!` isn't printed):

```
! Fatal Package bp2017 Error: The thing that wasn't supposed to happen
(bp2017)                      happened.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.14   { NO ERROR }

? h

I don't know how to help you further.

This is a fatal error: LaTeX will abort.

?


phelype@oleinik:~/home/phelype/tex.sx$
```

However this will not work with `standalone` because it does everything inside a `\vbox` (with the `varwidth` option), and when you use (TeX's) `\end` in a `\vbox` you get: `` ! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode. `` Without `varwidth`, then `standalone` uses an `\hbox`, and then you get a `! Missing } inserted.`

**Edit:** With an updated ([June 3rd, 2019](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/b83302b0d35456a7f1a54a79b3e440b3b5786cca)) version of `expl3`, `\msg_fatal:nn(nnnn)` ends the compilation regardless of where it's called from by issuing the error message and then having the underlying TeX engine stop with a low-level fatal error.

Comment: hmm I wonder if it ought to try harder to stop (put itself in batch mode `\vbox{\batchmode\end}
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I like the idea. It's supposed to stop the engine either way, so I guess it's better than _more_ error messages...